# Android memory usage increase when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a calculator app so I can get familiar with Java (just started learning) and the Android SDK. I have a question about memory usage. When ever I tap the "=" button, memory increases about 0.03 MB with each tap (even after the result variable reads "Infinity"). When I reach the heap limit it drops by about 8 MB. The method that is being called on the = button is this:

```
public double calculate() {
    switch(_op) {
        case '/':
            result = _firstnum / _secondnum;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = _firstnum * _secondnum;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = _firstnum - _secondnum;
            break;
        case '+':
            result = _firstnum + _secondnum;
            break;
    }

    _firstnum = result;

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not creating any variables or objects. All the variables referenced have already been declared and initialized. This method is just doing simple arithmetic, so why is it increasing memory usage?

Comment: How are you transfering the value from view to the variable _firstnum && _secondnum ?? can you show the piece of code ?

Comment: What's your problem? *You* might not be doing anything complex in your code, but the framework is doing a lot. Handling events, possibly sending them to other processes, possibly redrawing your activity. Since the memory get's freed when the heap limit is reached, there seems to be no memory leak.

Comment: @dhke That's what I thought. I was really just curious about what was happening behind the scenes. @Panther When the user presses a button I get the text value and convert it to a double and store it in the appropriate variable. To display the result I convert `result` to a string and display it in a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "0.03MB" of increase in memory usage is **fair**.

When you are pressing the "=" button, the method does the arithmetic operation. The operation is light-weight, but it is **not the only thing that is happening** at that moment in your app.

When ever you touch the screen, a touch event is intercepted and the required action is taken. The View may also be redrawn to show the result. There are so many other small Android processes happening **behind-the-scenes**.

So, there is absolutely nothing to worry about here. When the system deems fit, it will **automatically garbage collect unnecessary objects** and free up the heap.

Comment: +1 Its also important to note that the JVM provides more than one GC strategy. Depending on the lifecycle and number of objects which are added to the heap in a given application, one strategy may be favorable over another. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: Thanks. Like I said, I'm new to the whole Android development (mobile development in general). I like to know what's happening behind the scenes, I feel like it helps me be more aware of the environment I'm using.